# Metastable bound state in resonance scattering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, resonance

In resonance scattering, why does the mean lifetime of the "metastable" bound state depend inversely on the width of the resonance?

Comment: Use uncertainty principle, $\Delta E \,\, \Delta t \approx \hbar$?